# JPA ArgumentException error when doing JOIN FETCH on EAGER shared relation oneToOne

Tags: jpa, join, fetch, openjpa

I'm facing a problem with JOIN FETCH and EAGER relations.

I have the following entity relations:

Entity A extends abstract entity E.

Abstract entity E has a oneToOne bidirectional relation with Entity C with **EAGER fetch type**.

Entity A has oneToMany relation with Entity B.

Entity B extends abstract entity E (so have oneToOne relation too with C)

Entity C has inverse relation to abstract entity E

While executing a simple namedQuery like

```
SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.key = :key
```

Where parameter 'key' is String type, then i have no problem. Accessing to sub entities B from retrieved entity A execute sub requests as its supposed to be.

But if i add a JOIN FETCH to my namedQuery:

```
SELECT a FROM A a JOIN FETCH a.entitiesB WHERE a.key = :key
```

i obtain the following error stack trace:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: The transaction has been marked rollback only because the bean encountered a non-application exception :javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException : The transaction has been marked rollback only because the bean encountered a non-application exception :org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException : The specified parameter of type "class org.apache.openjpa.util.LongId" is not a valid query parameter.
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:345)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:283)
... 
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The specified parameter of type "class org.apache.openjpa.util.LongId" is not a valid query parameter.
FailedObject: SELECT relation FROM Relation relation JOIN FETCH relation.accounts WHERE relation.key = :key [java.lang.String]
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.setUnknown(DBDictionary.java:1458)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.setParameters(SQLBuffer.java:544)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:453)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLBuffer.prepareStatement(SQLBuffer.java:429)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SelectImpl.prepareStatement(SelectImpl.java:479)
...
```

If i change the EAGER relations to LAZY, i do not have this error anymore. So, what's the problem ?

Edit 1: I get the same error if i keep oneToOne relations with LAZY fetch type and add JOIN FETCH a.entityC directly on the namedQuery

Edit 2: Removing relation oneToOne with entity C from abstractEntity class and adding this relation directly into EntityA and EntityB (plus modifying entity C to have reverse relation with A & B), still keeping this oneToOne relation as EAGER => No problem.
So it looks like the problem come from having this shared relation into the abstract entity class, but why?

This is code example illustrated the problem.

*Entity A*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@NamedQueries({
   @NamedQuery(name = "findADetails", query = "SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.customKey.key     = :customKey")})
public class A extends abstractEntity {

   @Embedded
   private CustomEmbeddedKey customKey;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "entityA")
   private List<B> bEntities;

   ...
}
```

Entity B

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_B")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class B extends abstractEntity {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = A.class)
   @JoinColumn(name = "FK_A_ID")
   private A entityA;

   ...
}
```

*Abstract entity class*

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "TOTO_ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "TOTO_ID_SEQ", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public abstract class abstractEntity {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID")
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "TOTO_ID_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   private Long id;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "...", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   private C anotherEntity;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "...", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private List<D> anotherEntities;

   ...

}
```

*Embedded key*

```
@Embeddable
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class CustomEmbeddedKey {

   @Column(name = "...", length = ...)
   private String key;

   ...
}
```

*Dao sample*

```
TypedQuery<A> query = createNamedQuery("findADetails", A.class);
  query.setParameter("customKey", queryParam);
  List<A> aEntitiesFound = query.getResultList();
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think i found the problem. It's due to the mapping which not really supported by openJPA if we refer to the documentation on [Eager Fetching Considerations and Limitations](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.3/apache-openjpa-1.0.3/docs/manual/ref_guide_perfpack_eager.html)

So finally there are two solutions for me:

---

**Solution 1 (easy one):**

- Change fetch type EAGER to LAZY on the abstract entity class
- Add fetch groups and update each related namedQueries or code

**Advantages:**

- Quick solution and do not have lot of impacts on the existing code.

**Disadvantages:**

- Must investigate on usage of new LAZY fields + updates of related queries as it will be now lazy loaded per getters (if not from updated namedQueries)
- Running tests with Junit and dynamic enhancement will still throw NPE while doing JOIN FETCH on namedQueries with such mapping (Abstraction & TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance type)

---

**Solution 2:** Modify the mapping

- From abstract entity, remove usage of inheritance (no business usage in fact) and replace by @MappedSuperClass (and so remove @Entity and @Inheritance)
- Add an interface and define getters / setters of EAGER properties
- Implement this interface into the abstract entity class so that child classes has to implements getters / setters (and so the related properties and mapping)
- Change the type of reversed relation onto the target entity of these EAGER objects from abstract class type to new interface type
- Finally move implementation of mapping, getters and setters of the EAGER properties from abstract entity class to all child entity classes.

**Advantages:**

- No more exceptions (nor the NPE due to old mapping and dynamic class enhancement)
- Stronger solution because more chance to avoid further exception due to openJPA limitations on old mapping style

**Disadvantages:**

- More modifications
- Maybe less readable for devs due to interface instead of abstract class type into targetted entity classes